# kotlin variable with range or 2 values?

Tags: kotlin

I am trying to make out this line but I have found no explanation about it.

```
var max = Int.MIN_VALUE to 0
```

Is 'max' a kind of range or does it have 2 values(Int.MIN_VALUE and 0).
Where can I find any reference about it?

Comment: https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin/to.html

Answer (score 0):

`max` is an implicitly typed [Kotlin Pair](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin/-pair/).

It's the same as writing:

```kotlin
var max: Pair<Int, Int> = Pair(Int.MIN_VALUE, 0)
```

Comment: I think it would be better to compare `to` to a code that doesn't itself use `to` ;-) `var max = Pair(Int.MIN_VALUE, 0)`.

Comment: @broot, good point. Updated.